# How to use a redux toolkit slice with dependancies

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a redux slice that has dependencies: some data that needs to be kept between renders (which doesn't need to trigger a rerender, so a ref would be perfect). I currently use useRef, but that doesn't work because it's not inside a component. Any ideas on how to make this work without the ref?

I could ofcourse store it within the state, but that'd make the state a bit unwieldy where you actually need it: {settings, currentView} as I only need the settings.

```
const [getView, setView] = useRefSet("default"); // a simple wrapper around useRef to get get/set functions
const initialState = knobSettings.default;

const joinArrays = (original, newView) => ...;

const setFromViewLocal = (view) => {
    let settings = [...knobSettings.default];
    switch (view) {
        case "sequencer":
            setView("sequencer");
            return joinArrays(settings, knobSettings.sequencer);
        ...
        default:
            setView("default");
            return settings;
    }
};

export const knobSettingsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'knobSettings',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setFromView: (state, action) => setFromViewLocal(action.payload),
        setFromOverlay: (state, action) => joinArrays(state, action.payload),
        resetOverlay: (state) => setFromViewLocal(getView()),
    }
});

export const {setFromView, setFromOverlay, resetOverlay} = knobSettingsSlice.actions;

export default knobSettingsSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it in your slice. If none of your components selects it, it will not trigger a rerender - that's how `useSelector` works.

Comment: If I try to implement that, I get a new problem: `state.knobSettings` now has extra values, so instead of `useSelector(state => state.knobSettings)` I'll have to call `useSelector(state => state.knobSettings.knobSettings)`, is there a way to avoid this?

How would I only expose the part of the state that is needed for the components so they don't have to extract it themselves?

Comment: You should generally never select a full slice from state, but only the properties your component actually needs - even if that means calling `useSelector` multiple times.
https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#call-useselector-multiple-times-in-function-components

Comment: have it structured like const initialState = {
settings: {}
}

Maybe name your slice to knob 

then when you do useSelector(state => state.knob.settings)

or you can just have something like const { knobSettings } = useSelector(state => state.knobSettings)